# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{..} : java.lang.NullPointerException via Crashlytics. Cannot reproduce

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-activity

For ~20% of my user-base, they are getting a `Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{..} : java.lang.NullPointerException`FATAL Exception. I monitor the exceptions remotely via Crashlytics, so I have the stacktrace. The only problem is, there is no line number.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.falk.fietsroutes.app/com.falk.fietsroutes.app.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at com.falk.fietsroutes.app.SearchResultsFragment.onCreateView()
       at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1044)
       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1853)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5392)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

I've read many reports from people with the same error, which all came down to something in their code being null (ofcourse, because it's a nullpointer). But I can't track it down because I cannot reproduce it (I only have one device which seems to work fine), and the stack trace doesn't help.

At first sight I couldn't find anything that could be null in `SearchResultsFragment.onCreateView()` (because that is where the NPE gets thrown right?)

If any of you could point me in the right direction or know how I could get the line number where the exception, it would be appreciated!

Here is the code of `SearchResultsFragment.onCreateView()`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Set orientation
    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
    // Get the rootview in the fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_results, container, false);

    // Get settings instance
    mSettings = Settings.getInstance();
    // Init the mRoutes arraylist
    mRoutes = new ArrayList<Route>();
    // Get the gridview and set the adapters (animation adapter and the gridview adapter)
    GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    SearchResultCardsAdapter searchAdapter = new SearchResultCardsAdapter(getActivity(), inflater);
    SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter swingBottomInAnimationAdapter = new SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter(searchAdapter);
    swingBottomInAnimationAdapter.setAbsListView(gridView);
    swingBottomInAnimationAdapter.setInitialDelayMillis(300);
    mAdapter = swingBottomInAnimationAdapter;
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Log.d("Grid item click", "Clicked!");
            Route route = mRoutes.get(i);
            Intent routeDetailIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), RouteDetailActivity.class);
            routeDetailIntent.putExtra("routeId", route.id);
            // Analytics
            Tracker t = ((AppDelegate) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
                    AppDelegate.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
            // Build and send an Event.
            t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                    .setCategory("Routes")
                    .setAction("View")
                    .setLabel(Integer.toString(route.id))
                    .build());

            startActivity(routeDetailIntent);
        }
    });
    gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Set the infinite scroll listener
    gridView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
            // Triggered only when new data needs to be appended to the list
            // Add whatever code is needed to append new items to your AdapterView
            loadMoreRoutes(page, totalItemsCount);
            // or customLoadMoreDataFromApi(totalItemsCount);
        }
    });

    // Show the progressbar
    mProgressBar = (SmoothProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.search_results_progressbar);
    mProgressBar.progressiveStart();

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe others will benefit from my mistake. The problem was that I used pro-guard and Android Studio to sign my Android App, and I had to `keep-attributes` some properties so Crashlytics could read the line number and class name.

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

[Via](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/202926-android-studio-and-intellij-with-proguard)